# Running MySQL query from Python 2.4 while not installing modules (MySQLdb)

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error, subprocess

I need to run a MySQL query from Python 2.4 but I cannot download/install any modules for Python.

The reason I cannot download is because this script is to be run on servers (RedHat) and our customers will not let us download and install anything.

I've been trying to use `subprocess`, but the query I'm using is giving me a `syntax error`.

The query works outside of Python if I run it from a query browser, but adding the quotes and commas inside the subprocess command `[]` makes things a little confusing.

The command I'm trying to run is as follows:

```
subprocess.call(['mysql', '-D DB', '--user="user"', '--password="password"', '-e', '"SELECT cu, control_name FROM PresetProfile WHERE NOT cu='' AND NOT control_name='' INTO OUTFILE '/directory/for/output.file' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"', shell=True])
```

The Syntax error I get points to the single quote immediately before the `:` after `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`.

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
subprocess.call(['mysql', '-D DB', '--user="user"', '--password="password"', '-e', '"SELECT cu, control_name FROM PresetProfile WHERE NOT cu='' AND NOT control_name='' INTO OUTFILE '/directory/for/output.file' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"', shell=True])
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Once I get this output file created, I can stop using subprocess and get back to regular file processing.

Comment: As you can see in your question (see the syntax highlighting), there's a quoting issue

Comment: I would give [commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html) a try to run a MySQL command

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Python? A simple bash script would be a lot simpler to escape.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is this:  `'"SELECT cu, control_name FROM PresetProfile WHERE NOT cu='' AND NOT control_name='' INTO OUTFILE '/directory/for/output.file' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"'`

Notice that you have `'` inside your string -- you'll need to escape them or use triple quotes.

`'"SELECT cu, control_name FROM PresetProfile WHERE NOT cu=\'\' AND NOT control_name=\'\' INTO OUTFILE \'/directory/for/output.file\' FIELDS TERMINATED BY \':\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\';"'`

Also you'll probably want to drop the `shell=True` bit -- Managing the escaping is hard enough if you're only dealing with Python.  Once you need to un-escape it again for the shell things get even more messy.

Comment: If dropping `shell=True`, then it might be prudent to put the full path for the `mysql` binary.